# Cannot map network disk

Tags: networking, hard-drive

I have a NAS, problem is that I cannot map network disk in NAS.

Command:

```
net use u: \\192.168.1.3\home
```

Output:

> ```
> System error 59 has occured.
>
> An unexpected network error occurred.
> ```

I am using Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, NAS is on the same LAN. I tried to map it from another computer in the same network and it works, but it doesn't work on my PC.

**I tried to:**

- disable the firewall;
- ping the NAS – success;
- log into NAS webadmin – success;
- remove my network adapter and reinstall its network driver;
- change *Network security: LAN Manager authentication level* to *Send LM & NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if negotiated* in `Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options` using `gpedit.msc`;
- create a new key `Smb2` in
  `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters` to
  `0` and `1` (second try);
- create a new key `EnableDfsLoopbackTargets` in `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Mup\Parameters` with value `1`.

Comment: What troubleshooting have you tried? Did you check the top couple results in Google when you search for this error (Microsoft has an article specifically about this)?

Comment: can you ping the IP? can you telnet to it on 445? If you can connect to it from one device on the same network, then the issue is likely on the host that is failing, or in the protocol it is trying to use to connect (if both same OS, then not likely protocol, possibly software firewall).

Comment: I updated the main post, what I tried to do.

Comment: Is the nas blocking the connection to that specific pc/IP? I've had that before

Comment: I dont think so, I can ping NAS and login into WebAdmin, also I tried remove network driver and reinstall driver but it doesnt help

Comment: What about telnet/netcat on 445? ping just means you have IP routing to it, webui is port 80 or 8080, but doesn't clear TCP on the port you need for files. Validate that 445 works.